# Make a set of 3D points rotate around a point

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, lwjgl, trigonometry

What is the formula for calculating the position of 3D point after it has been rotated around another 3D point a certain radians/degrees? I am using Java / LWLJGL.

Could someone just fill in the blanks in the following?
    `public Vector3f rotate(Vector3f origin, Vector3f rotation)

    {

        Vector3f ret = new Vector3f();

        ret.x = __________;

        ret.y = __________;

        ret.z = __________;

    }`

Comment: Rotation in 3D requires two angles and is not commutative. Before we answer, can you confirm that you have both of the paramters avaiable?

Comment: @hexafraction - Well, I was going to have 3 rotation parameters - the x, y, and z rotations (and the point to rotate around)

Comment: There's no such thing as x, y, and z rotations. There are only two angles involved, just like in two dimensions only one angle is involved. To informally prove this, take a point in 2D and try to rotate it in two different *independent* ways.

Comment: @hexafraction what about pitch, yaw, and roll?

Comment: That can't be done with a point. A point has no internal orientation.

Comment: That makes sense. So What would the formula be? Or is it not that simple?

Comment: Use vector mathematics. You'll also need to work with matrices quite a bit. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Three_dimensions. You'll need to construct a matrix with a certain discriminant and mutliply it by another.

Comment: I don't know vector mathematics, that's why I'm here...

Comment: 3D rotation is quite complex and twisted(no pun intended). You'll find that a lot of mathematics becomes immensely complex in the third dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your fixed point has coordinates (a,b,c) and moving object (x1,y1,z1) at time `t1` and at (x2,y2,z2) at time `t2`.

option 1
you can consider projection on `x-y`plane and projection on `y-z` plane and calculate angle in that 2D space.

option 2
you can consider two vectors. say vector `A` and `B`

```
A=(x1-a)i+(y1-b)j+(z1-c)k 
B=(x2-a)i+(y2-b)j+(z2-c)k
```

Now use dot product of `A` and `B`

```
 A . B = |A||B|cos(angle)
```

Comment: I am confused now. What are t1, t2, A, and B? Can't you just write a method like:`public Vector3f rotate(Vector3f origin, Vector3f rotation){  float x=...  float y=...  float z=...  }`

Comment: @user2529202 Rotation is only two angles. The mathematics in this post is sound, now you can construct a method that uses the mathematics here.

Comment: @user2529202 you no need to worry about t1 and t2. I used them to explain. you only want to know three points(fixed point and two location of rotating point). you can find A and B from those. I suggest you to learn about vectors.refer this http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html. if there any thing unclear, leave a comment here.